# Markers in Android Google Maps v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

There is some way to make a OnLongClickListener in Markers without making them draggable?
I'm trying to show a context menu where a Marker is long clicked, so I implements the OnMarkerDragListener interface to handle them with this code:

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    marker.setDraggable(false);

    if (mode == MODE_VIEW) {
        registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));
        openContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));
        unregisterForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));
    }

    marker.setDraggable(true);
}
```

but when I press in the Marker she moves up! because that's the way how draggable works.
what should I do? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no onLongClickListener for markers currently

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add another hack to your code and force the original position.

```
marker.setDraggable(false);
LatLng originalPosition = mapWithOriginalPositionsOfAllMarkers.get(marker);
marker.setPosition(originalPosition);
```

This hack may cause visual glitch, but the marker will go back to where it should.

Additionaly you need to keep references to original positions:

```
// Activity field
private Map<Marker, LatLng> mapWithOriginalPositionsOfAllMarkers = new HashMap<Marker, LatLng>();

// when adding marker:
LatLng position = ...
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
mapWithOriginalPositionsOfAllMarkers.put(marker, position);
```